# macOS llvm can't find stdio.h anymore

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code, clang, llvm

I come to you with a weird problem I've been facing.
So last week, I installed llvm and libomp for a C project, and it compiled just fine with this at the start of my makefile:

```
CC=clang
CFLAGS = -O2 -fopenmp
CFLAGS += -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include
LDFLAGS = -fopenmp
LDFLAGS += -L /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib
```

Today I meant to finish that project, I opened vs code (I don't know if that's relevant), added some code left and right, and when I wanted to compile the code again to test if everything was fine, it gave me

```
me@macbookPro% make
clang -c  -O2 -fopenmp -I/usr/local/opt/libomp/include bubble.c -o bubble.o
bubble.c:1:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [bubble.o] Error 1
```

which has left me dumbfounded since it worked just fine a few days ago.
I tried to do an export CPATH with

```
export CPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
```

but I got a bunch of warning and it didn't work either.
Any help is greatly appreciated !

Info: I'm running the latest version of BigSur and VSCode.

Comment: Do you have the Big Sur version of XCode installed (still)?  If not, try reinstalling it.  If so, you're probably not using the XCode `clang`, and you probably need to upgrade the `clang` you are using.  Also, you have `/usr/include` on the end of your CPATH value — have you tried dropping the `/include`, or even `/usr/include`?  I think CPATH is for more than just the path to the headers (but I've not thoroughly investigated that).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for answering. I do use the right clang:

`% clang --version

clang version 11.1.0

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0

Thread model: posix

InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin`

I have tried shortening the include to drop usr/include and it's not working either.
I also ran `brew update && brew upgrade`, everything is up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently a macOS update had uninstalled the XCode developer tools.

I ended up uninstalling `llvm` and `libomp`, and when reinstalling it told me brew didn't have `CLT` (use `brew config` to check that).

Then I ran the classic `xcode-select --install` then `brew install llvm` and `brew install libomp`, edited my path to include the llvm's bin and it works again.

Comment: does not work for me on macOS montery. When I run `xcode-select --install`, it shows that command line tools have been installed.

Comment: Hello @jdhao ! In my experience, launching XCode fixes the problem. Every time there's a major macOS update, I usually need to restart XCode at least once and make sure the Xcode command line tools are up to date. Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

- masOS12.3.1 monterey

"software update" --> "update commandLineTool" if push --> you can compile correctly without 'stdio.h' file not found.